# Why does grep work differently in Debian vs CentOs?

Tags: linux, grep, centos, debian

Take this simple shell function...

```
function search (){
    grep -roiI --include $2 $1 . | sort -u
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
# search drop *.properties
```

In CentOs it will function as desired returning a list of grep'd results. However, in Debian, it parses the special chars in "*.properties" as a regex, thus not grep'ing properly. Why is Debian parsing special chars and CentOs not?

Comment: By the way, you can use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`

Comment: Good idea. I wonder why I was thumbed down. :( 
 ~ I R SAD NOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like different settings for the `nullglob` shell option which controls what happens when you use a glob (something with a wildcard) and there are no files matching that glob.  With nullglob turned on, this would treat "*.properties" as a list of files, even if that was an empty list, with nullglob turned off, this would treat "*.properties" as a string if it didn't match any files.  You can try disabling nullglob with `shopt -u nullglob` and turn it back on with `shopt -s nullglob`.

However, in this case, when you do NOT want *.properties to be treated as a glob ever, and you want this string to be passed directly into your script, you should be either escaping the * as `search drop \*.properties` or you should be quoting the string with either double or single quotes: `search drop '*.properties'`.  Similarly, in your search script, you should be enclosing the `$2`, `$1` parameters in double qoutes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `grep` is not the issue. It can be a shell expansion problem.

On [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

```
Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’. If one of these
characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with
an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern.
```